# 2D Matrix prints extra row?

Tags: c, minesweeper

I was coding a minesweeper game in c, and it works just fine most of the time, but I found an strange bug in which when I play the cell in the first column of the first row and it is a 0 the board has either an extra row or a row has changed positions and moved to the top. I think this comes from my expand function, as it wasn't happening before I implemented it.

This is my code:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIM 8
#define DENSITY 0.2

void print_matrix(int (*)[DIM], int);
void generate_map(float, int(*)[DIM], int);
void generate_numbers(int(*)[DIM], int(*)[DIM], int, int*);
void minesweeper(int (*)[DIM], int(*)[DIM], int(*)[DIM], int*, int, int, int);
int win(int (*)[DIM], int, int);
void expand(int (*)[DIM], int (*)[DIM], int, int, int, int, int);

int main(void) {
    int map[DIM][DIM], numbers[DIM][DIM], row, column, game, mines = 0;
    char exit;

    do {
        game = 1; mines = 0;
        int visible[DIM][DIM] = { [0 ... DIM-1][0 ... DIM-1] = -1 };
        srand(time(NULL));
        do generate_map(DENSITY, map, DIM); while (mines < DIM);
        generate_numbers(numbers, map, DIM, &mines);
        do {
            print_matrix(numbers, DIM);
            puts("Map");
            print_matrix(map, DIM);
            printf("\nNumber of mines: %d", mines);
            do {
                printf("\nEnter the selected row (MAX. %d): ", DIM);
                scanf("%d", &row);
            } while (row <= 0 || row > DIM);
            do {
                printf("\nEnter the selected column (MAX. %d): ", DIM);
                scanf("%d", &column);
            } while (column <= 0 || column > DIM);
            system("cls");

            minesweeper(numbers, map, visible, &game, row - 1, column - 1, DIM);
            print_matrix(visible, DIM);
            puts("Numbers");

            if (win(visible, DIM, mines)) {
                printf("CONGRATULATIONS, YOU WON!!");
                game = 0;
            }
        } while (game);

        printf("\nEND OF THE GAME");
        printf("\nDo you want to play again? (Y/N): ");
        fflush(stdout);
        scanf(" %c", &exit);

    } while (toupper(exit) == 'Y');
}

void generate_map(float density, int(*map)[DIM], int dim) {
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < dim; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < dim; c++) {
            map[r][c] = (float)rand() / RAND_MAX > density ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }
}

void generate_numbers(int (*numbers)[DIM], int (*map)[DIM], int dim, int *mines) {
    int counter, r, c, i, j;
    for (r = 0; r < dim; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < dim; c++) {
            counter = 0;
            for (i = r - 1; i <= r + 1; i++) {
                if (i > -1 && i < dim) {
                    for (j = c - 1; j <= c + 1; j++) {
                        if (j > -1 && j < dim) {
                            if (map[i][j] != 0) {
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            numbers[r][c] = counter;
            if (map[r][c] != 0) *mines += 1;
        }
    }
}

void minesweeper(int (*numbers)[DIM], int (*map)[DIM], int (*visible)[DIM], int *game, int row, int column, int dim) {
    if (map[row][column] == 0) {
        if (numbers[row][column] == 0) {
            expand(numbers, visible, dim, row, column, row, column);
        } else {
            visible[row][column] = numbers[row][column];
        }
    } else {
        visible[row][column] = -2;
        *game = 0;
    }
}

void print_matrix(int (*m)[DIM], int dim) {
    int r, c;
    for (r = 0; r < dim; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < dim; c++) {
            if (m[r][c] == -1) {
                printf("| x ");
            } else if (m[r][c] == -2) {
                printf("| * ");
            } else {
                printf("| %d ", m[r][c]);
            }
        }
        printf("|\n");
    }
}

int win(int (*visible)[DIM], int dim, int mines) {
    int c, r, counter;
    for (r = 0; r < dim; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < dim; c++) {
            if (visible[r][c] == -1) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return (counter == mines) ? 1 : 0;
}

void expand(int (*numbers)[DIM], int (*visible)[DIM], int dim, int row, int column, int i_o, int j_o) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++) {
        if (i > -1 && i < dim) {
            for (j = column - 1; j <= column + 1; j++) {
                if (j > -1 && j < dim) {
                    if ((i == i_o && j == j_o) || (i == row && j == column)) {
                        continue;
                    } else if (numbers[i][j] == 0 && visible[i][j] == -1) {
                        visible[i][j] = numbers[i][j];
                        expand(numbers, visible, dim, i, j, row, column);
                    } else {
                        visible[i][j] = numbers[i][j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Firstly I create the map matrix, which has the positions of the mines, then I create another matrix with the number of mines surrounding that cell and then I use the matrix visible to print what the player can see. The `expand()` function is activated when the number is 0 in a given cell, and it makes visible all surrounding cells as none of them are mines, if one of those numbers is 0 it is called again with the coordenates of the 0 from the last iteration (io, jo), so it doesn't create infinite recursion. `minesweeper()` is the funcion that plays a given cell. I don't think it is a limit problem because it always checks for them.

In the attatchment you can see the problem I was talking about, it printed 9 rows instead of 8 and the top one is just a visible copy of the seventh one. The only move I did prior to the screenshot was playing the cell (1,1), which is a 0, so the expand function was called and it works as expected except that it created and extra row above it and the cell (1,1) is still invisible, it only became visible once i played the cell (1,2).  (It is from an earlier Spanish version)

It all worked out when I added `visible[i][j] = numbers[i][j];` before the `continue;` in the expand function. But I still want to know why it printed and extra row. Does anybody know why this could happend?

Comment: OT: Call `srand` only *once* in your program.

Comment: As for your problem, in the input loops you have the condition `row > DIM`. That allows the user to input a value such as `row == DIM`, which is out of bounds. I'm guessing you have something similar for your output, where you include `DIM` as a valid index when it isn't.

Comment: As another example lets take the `generate_numbers` function. In it you have the loop `for (r = 0; r < dim; r++)` and inside that loop you have the nested loop `for (i = r - 1; i <= r + 1; i++)`. This will allow `i` to be equal to `r + 1`. And when `r == (DIM - 1)` (the last iteration of the outer loop) then `i` can be equal to `DIM`. Which is out of bounds.

Comment: Depending on your compiler I suggest you use its built-in sanitizer to catch these errors. For example if you build with GCC or Clang, add the flags `-g -fsanitize=address`.

Comment: By the way, where in the loop `do generate_map(DENSITY, map, DIM); while (mines < DIM)` do you modify the value of `mines`? Because you don't, that's an infinite loop.

Comment: You need to build with a sanitizer (if available), with extra warning enabled and treated as errors, and take the time to step though your code line by line in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems). I also suggest you don't try to cram multiple statements into single lines, that makes the code harder to read *and* debug (since debugging is usually line-based). I'll bet there are plenty of other small but significant errors in your code, that I haven't discovered yet.

Comment: And a last tip: Don't write large bits of code all at once. Instead start with an empty `main` function. Build (with extra warnings, treated as errors). When it builds without errors, tes the program. Then add a ***very small*** bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Build and test as before. This will make it much easier to catch mistakes and problems, and also to debug them. Perhaps even create a [mre] to test and debug the problem in isolation.

Comment: I have those input conditions because I want the user to start counting at 1, the actual values are `r-1,c-1` . In `generate_numbers()` and all the other loops I always check if that particular i or j is out of bouds: `if (i > -1 && i < dim)`  and `generate_map()` passes mines by reference so that part works just fine.

Comment: `generate_map` does not take `mines` as an argument. By value or a pointer to it. Are you showing us the correct [mre]? Did you copy-paste the actual code?

Comment: No, sorry, that is `generate_numbers()` you are right. But that still doesn't explain why it printed an extra row.

Comment: Use a debugger to find out why.

Comment: You shouldn't name a variable `exit`. That name is reserved for the function with that name located in `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Instead of functions accepting different parts of the game logic, why don't you bundle all the logic in a `struct` and then pass a pointer to that around?